# GNU make: how to rebuild sentinel targets when a generated file is deleted?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, code-generation

A code generator is executed from GNU make. The generator produces several files (depending on the input), and only touches the files, when their content change. Therefore a sentinel target needs to be used to record the generator execution time:

```
GEN_READY : $(gen_input_files)
    gen.exe $(gen_input_files)
    touch GEN_READY

$(gen_output_files): GEN_READY
```

It works well, except when a generated file is deleted, but the sentinel file is left in place. Since the sentinel is there, and it's up-to-date, the generator is not executed again.
What is the proper solution to force make to re-run the generator in this case?

Comment: If you have Make 4.3 you can try grouped targets. If not you could look into grouping them by archives, and declare rules like target.tar:prerequisite.tar. Having the sentinel filename generated from input file hashes is one technique that works well, but may take longer to explain than a comment... Got any preference?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm experimenting with grouped targets now. Apart from 4.3+ only, that might be a problem, I encountered another one when chaining rules. Might be possible to fix though. Archives sound interesting, that feature I never tried, looking at it. Hashing is definitely too complicated here.

Comment: The Automake manual has a relatively lengthy discussion of [handling tools that produce multiple outputs](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Multiple-Outputs), including by using sentinel files.  Notwithstanding its source, the discussion is general to a wide variety of `make` implementations, not specific to Automake.  I think you would find it worth a read.

Comment: This is definitely interesting and useful information, many thanks. The final solution might not work in GNU make. It's horribly complicated, uses recursive make call, and not sure how to test many generated files.

Comment: There's an Ask Mr. Make [article](https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/atomic-rules-gnu-make) from 2007 on using atomic rules and sentinel files with GNU Make.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to group them using an archive:

```
# create archive of output files from input files passed through gen.exe
GEN_READY.tar: $(gen_input_files)
    @echo Generate the files
    gen.exe $^
    @echo Put generated files in archive
    tar -c -f $@ $(gen_output_files)
    @echo Remove intermediate files (recreated by next recipe)
    rm $(gen_output_files)

# Extracting individual files for use as prerequisite or restoration
$(gen_output_files): GEN_READY.tar
    @echo Extract one member
    tar -x -f $< $@
```

Since tar (and zip for that matter) allows duplicate entries there could be opportunities updating or appending files in archive instead of rewriting if input-output relation allows.

---

Edit: Simplified solution.

Comment: I realize this answer does not actually apply for the question, as the sentinel file was dropped. Oh well, someone might find it useful anyway.

Comment: It's certainly useful as I never used archives in make and not familiar with the syntax. I'm wondering whether this could be used without actually creating archives, just to group the targets...

Comment: Edited so to cover the case when one file is deleted, in which case current answer will restore the file from the semi-intermediate archive.